# Opening PPT file in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to link a ppt file to one of XAML pages in Windows phone 7. I have the file stored online. What should ideally happen is when the user clicks the appbar icon, it should open using a PPT Viewer in the phone, similar the launcher tasks available link ShareStatusTask, BingMapsTask etc.,

```
private void appbarPresentationClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  WebBrowserTask pptTask = new WebBrowserTask();
  pptTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/26/3320306/Emerging%20Technologies.pptx");
  pptTask.Show();
}
```

This opens the web browser and then opens the ppt file. Is there a better way to achieve this as to directly launching he PPT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way of opening such files.

The method you are using is the only one available.

Comment: Is there any improvement on this topic? I mean, is there a way to present the pptx and docx files to WP7 users through our app now??

Comment: @Apoorva you'd have to add your own way to select and open the files. The you'd have to open and display the contents appropriately. Expect a LOT of work to recreate the native experience of viewing such files.

Comment: when WP devices have in built office, why cant MS provide developers the privilege to use it to display MS-Office contents!! They should consider doing this..